# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: reactjs

I am following a youtube tutorial and we **returned** conditional HTML elements if **post.length** is 0 or not but I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

```
const Posts = () => {
const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts)

return (
!posts.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
  <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
    {posts.map((post) => (
      <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Post post={post}/>
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
 )
);
};
```

So I tried to use the following traditional if statement to see if I made a syntax error but seems like it wasn't the case

```
if (!posts.length) {
return <CircularProgress />
} else {
<Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
    {posts.map((post) => (
      <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Post post={post}/>
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have posts already defined in the component with a console log :

```
console.log(posts);
```

If it is defined then you need to change the `posts.length` code to this code :

```
if (posts && !posts.length) {
return <CircularProgress />
} else {
<Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
    {posts && posts.map((post) => (
      <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Post post={post}/>
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
}
```

This way we are saying that get the length of the posts only when it gets available in the component .

Comment: I actually console logged posts yet it still it returns **undefined** and I also added "posts &&" part but the result is same

Comment: @TurhanErgene Then make sure this part of your code works ```const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts)```

Comment: const reduxState = useSelector((state) => state);
  const data = reduxState.Posts; I made so instead

Comment: @TurhanErgene Please accept answer if it helped you in anyway .